# How can I loop through and process files from a directory individually?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a function that iteratively loops through a bunch of .txt files in a directory and processes them individually. After a file has been processed I would like to plot output variables, then on the next iteration plot the new variables on the same graph. My code is shown below however does not seem to be working, it returns a 'output argument 'output1' (and maybe others) not assigned during call to function2.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
function [output1, output2, fig] = Processing(Folder_1,Folder_2,Folder_3)
%% Read in all the Data

% Initialise Loop to process each file independently
for i = 1 : length(Text_Files1)

Sorted_Index1 = Indices1(i);
Path1 = fullfile(Folder_1,Text_Files1(Sorted_Index1).name);
Table1 = readtable(Path1);

Sorted_Index2 = Indices2(i);
Path2 = fullfile(Folder_2,Text_Files2(Sorted_Index2).name);
Table2 = readtable(Path2);

Sorted_Index3 = Indices3(i);
Path3 = fullfile(Folder_3,Text_Files3(Sorted_Index3).name);
Table3 = readtable(Path3,'Delimiter',';');

%% Process Data through the Loop
[HR] = function1(processed_data)

[output1 output2] = function2(HR, Time);
hold on
fig = figure('Visible', false);
subplot(10,10,1:90)
plot(output2, output1, 'Color', [0.92 0.47 0.44], 'LineWidth', 1.5);
end
end
```

%% Function 2:

```
function [output1, output2] = function2(t, y, z)

segment = 1:z:max(y);

% Iterate through each time segment and calculate average t value
for x = 1:length(segment)-1
    
        SegmentScores = find(y > segment(x) & ...
        y < segment(x+1));
    
    output1(x) = mean(y(SegmentScores));
    
    output2(x) = Segment(x+1); 
    
end

end
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) only.

Comment: Have trimmed it down a good bit, hopefully makes sense!

Comment: Much better. On the other hand, the error implies that inside your function2 you're not setting any output; without looking at that function, it is impossible to help you though.

Comment: If I set i equal to 1, function2 works fine and outputs results as expected, it is just whenever I try to iterate it over the loop I encounter the error

Comment: Added in function2, both outputs are set in it which is why I cant understand the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `function2(HR, Time)` with two inputs, while it needs three `function2(t, y, z)`.

For that reason, I'm assuming that inside function2 `segment` is an empty array, and thus the loop `for x = 1:length(segment) - 1` is not entered at all.

Since the definition of `output1` and `output2` is only inside the loop, they will never be created and thus the error.

If you provide three inputs to your `function2`, the problem will be solved. Just pay attention to the order in which you provide them (for example, I'm assuming your `Time` input should be the same as `t` in the function, so it should be the first input to be passed).

Comment: If it helped, consider accepting this answer.